# In Case of custom Exception Set Step Execution Status other than ABANDONED

Tags: spring-batch

I have situation where step can throw custom exception and the execution of job stops on exception. The problem I'm facing is, on exception in 'step2', Spring Batch set step status 'ABANDONED', I tried overriding step status by afterStep method and by explicitly stating status on SetpExecution instance available in afterStep method. However, in database tables, status for step 'step2' is 'ABANDONED'. I need to set it as finished so that I can restart the job and rerun the step. Any help?

Below is job configuration.

```
<batch:job id="TestJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="Step1">
        <tasklet ref="ValidatorTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
        <!-- <batch:end on="*" /> -->
        <batch:next on="*" to="step2" />
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="sendErrorEmail" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"
            allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="HeaderReader" processor="HeaderProcessor"
                writer="hibernateItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <!-- <batch:end on="*" /> -->
        <batch:next on="*" to="step3" />
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="sendErrorEmail" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step3">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"
            allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="TrailerReader" processor="TrailerProcessor"
                writer="hibernateItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:end on="*" />
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="sendErrorEmail" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="sendErrorEmail">
        <tasklet ref="SendErrorEmailTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
        <batch:fail on="*" exit-code="FAILED" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Stack Trace

```
2014-10-07 10:10:20,301 DEBUG [main] c.f.p.b.p.HeaderProcessor [OCLogger.java:154] HeaderProcessor.process HeaderProcDTO.toString HeaderProcDTO [FepFileId=0, abtEibfil01=null, bcbsPlanCd=277, fepJobRunDt=Tue Oct 07 10:10:20 EDT 2014, HdrProcTxt=PLANPDR_REQUEST_DETAILS, HeaderCd=PDEADRRH, PlanCntlId=1, PlanFileNm=Request_277_20141006020002.xml, PlanFileTs=2014-10-05 22:00:00.0, ProcJobId=149, TrailerProcDTO=null]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,301 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.s.t.TaskletStep [TaskletStep.java:437] Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=1, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,301 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.s.t.TaskletStep [TaskletStep.java:473] Rollback for Exception: java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
2014-10-07 10:10:20,306 DEBUG [main] o.s.t.s.TransactionTemplate [TransactionTemplate.java:162] Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.UncheckedTransactionException: java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:476) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.execute(BatchApplication.java:94) [bin/:na]
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:127) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:83) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:1) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
2014-10-07 10:10:20,306 DEBUG [main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:847] Initiating transaction rollback
2014-10-07 10:10:20,307 DEBUG [main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager [HibernateTransactionManager.java:571] Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3b1f3b updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@316b316b deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@314b314b orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33a533a5 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@662e662e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33373337 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33573357 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33853385 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,317 DEBUG [main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager [HibernateTransactionManager.java:633] Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3b1f3b updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@316b316b deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@314b314b orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33a533a5 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@662e662e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33373337 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33573357 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@33853385 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
2014-10-07 10:10:20,319 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.r.s.RepeatTemplate [RepeatTemplate.java:292] Handling exception: java.lang.Exception, caused by: java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
2014-10-07 10:10:20,320 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.r.s.RepeatTemplate [RepeatTemplate.java:252] Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
2014-10-07 10:10:20,321 ERROR [main] o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [AbstractStep.java:225] Encountered an error executing step readHeaderStep in job readHeaderJob
java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:83) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:1) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.execute(BatchApplication.java:94) [bin/:na]
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:127) [bin/:na]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,322 DEBUG [main] c.f.p.b.p.HeaderProcessor [OCLogger.java:154] HeaderProcessor.afterStep jobId : 149 Step Name : readHeaderStep Plan Code : 277
2014-10-07 10:10:20,322 DEBUG [main] c.f.p.b.p.HeaderProcessor [OCLogger.java:154] HeaderProcessor.afterStep HeaderProcDTO.toString HeaderProcDTO [FepFileId=0, abtEibfil01=null, bcbsPlanCd=277, fepJobRunDt=Tue Oct 07 10:10:20 EDT 2014, HdrProcTxt=PLANPDR_REQUEST_DETAILS, HeaderCd=PDEADRRH, PlanCntlId=1, PlanFileNm=Request_277_20141006020002.xml, PlanFileTs=2014-10-05 22:00:00.0, ProcJobId=149, TrailerProcDTO=null]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,323 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:367] Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2014-10-07 10:10:20,324 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:206] Acquired Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] for JDBC transaction
2014-10-07 10:10:20,325 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:223] Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] to manual commit
2014-10-07 10:10:20,326 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [JdbcTemplate.java:908] Executing prepared SQL update
2014-10-07 10:10:20,326 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [JdbcTemplate.java:627] Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,329 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [JdbcTemplate.java:918] SQL update affected 1 rows
2014-10-07 10:10:20,330 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755] Initiating transaction commit
2014-10-07 10:10:20,330 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:266] Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server]
2014-10-07 10:10:20,333 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:324] Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] after transaction
2014-10-07 10:10:20,333 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceUtils [DataSourceUtils.java:327] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2014-10-07 10:10:20,334 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:367] Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2014-10-07 10:10:20,334 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:206] Acquired Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] for JDBC transaction
2014-10-07 10:10:20,335 DEBUG [main] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:223] Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://FEPSQLVS2\sqlserver2:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=OCPRCDEV;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=OCPRCDEV_app, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] to manual commit
2014-10-07 10:10:20,336 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.r.d.JdbcStepExecutionDao [JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:273] Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: java.lang.Exception: Custom Exception from HeaderProcessor.process
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:83)
    at com.fepoc.batch.processor.HeaderProcessor.process(HeaderProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.execute(BatchApplication.java:94)
    at com.fepoc.batch.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:127)
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of an example exception that is setting the state to `ABANDONED`?

Comment: Is my question incorrect or there is no way in spring-batch to override and set step status?

Comment: Correct.  We don't allow you to override the `BatchStatus`.  It is managed internally by the framework.  What you manage is the `ExitStatus` which can be any value you want.  It's the `ExitStatus` that is also what we use to determine what step to execute next (not the `BatchStatus`.

Comment: The reason I want to update 'BatchStates' is if steps fails due to exception, then status is ‘ABANDONED’ and exit code is ‘FAILED’  in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table. And when the same job (with exact same job parameters) is restarted, batch throws error ‘Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute’, even though  the exception is not there. I think it means the steps will never be executed for same job.  I need to restart the job and execute the steps one more time with corrected data so that process can move to next step. Any suggestion or alternative for this scenario?

Comment: @Michael Minella Do you think the above requirement can be satisfied with some other alternative. If yes, appreciate your help here.

Comment: I tried taking the step out of the current job and created new job with only one step I needed to test for exception scenario. To my surprise, when exception is thrown from tasklet, spring-batch updated the status and exit code to **‘FAILED’** as against status is **‘ABANDONED’** and exit code is **‘FAILED’** in case same tasklet is part of multistep/tasklet job.

Comment: Moreover, when I rerun the job with single step, it allowed me to rerun the step as well, instead of throwing **‘‘Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute’’** message, as status is **‘FAILED’** instead of **‘ABANDONED’**. Can anyone help here to understand Spring-Batch behavior in case of custom exception thrown from tasklet? This is kinda showstopper for my progress, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Vinay, have you been able to answer your own question? I'm facing some of the same issues right now. I really want an exception escaping an `ItemReader` to cause the step to fail, but it won't right now.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed, I couldn't find solution within spring batch, however, I have included additional step before job starts to check if there are any ‘ABANDONED’ steps and update them as per the exception information available. I manged restart by updating status to failed. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vinay, thank you! I'm sorry that kind of crude workaround is required but it sounds like it will do the trick. They should really make this more flexible, as it feels like they're ramming that "you can't restart a step if it fails" rule down our throats!